# Is the diagram of the Egyptian trinity a copy of a pictogram on an obelisk?

Tags: ancient-egypt, mathematics

Is this diagram of the [Egyptian trinity](https://web.stanford.edu/group/kircher/cgi-bin/site/?attachment_id=761) a copy of a pictogram on an obelisk?

[image]

It would be nice to know this and get some pictures of it and know more about the history of this particular obelisk.

Comment: Considering that "Kircher's erroneous translations were carved in granite and fixed to the sides of the obelisk's pedestal, above Bernini's fountain, where they still stand today.[3]" (from the Wikipedia article [Obeliscus Pamphilius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obeliscus_Pamphilius) - and the fact that Egyptian hieroglyphics have nothing to do with "pictograms" -  this seems unlikely.

Comment: I wish i could take a look at the obelisk and find out what really is engraved. It seems unreal with all the camera's we have that there are no pictures verifying this drawing.

Answer (score 4):

No, its not. In fact, that appears to be nonsense. However, its interesting 17th century nonsense.

The obelisk in question, I'm not sure where the original is, but there's a copy to this day standing at [a fountain in the Piazza Navona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontana_dei_Quattro_Fiumi) in Rome. As for the original...

> The obelisk, made of Aswan granite, has an interesting history. It is
> connected with the emperor Domitian, and was originally thought to
> have come from the Serapeum, which the emperor rebuilt in A.D. 80.
> However, it is equally plausible that the obelisk might have
> originated from the Temple of the Gens Flavia on the Quirinal Hill,
> built by Domitian dedicated to his family cult. The hieroglyphic
> inscriptions on the obelisk were of Roman authorship, offering a hymn
> to Domitian, and the deified emperors Vespasian and Titus, possibly on
> the occasion of something being restored.

It was moved in the 4th Century, after which both its original location and the knowledge of how to read the hieroglyphic carved upon it were lost. However, it still looked really cool, and the lost language on it added a healthy dollop of mystique. In the early 1600's [Pope Innocent X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Innocent_X) decided to have it moved again, to the plaza in front of his family home, with a suitable setting, of course, and commissioned a Jesuit scholar named [Athanasius Kircher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athanasius_Kircher) to oversee the effort.

As I said, the knowledge of translating hieroglyphics was lost at that time, and not really regained for another 200 years. Kircher didn't let that stop him though, and attempted his own translation anyway. To be fair to him, *someone* eventually had to be the person to figure it out, so why not him?

Well ... it wasn't him. Boyohboy was it not him. In particular, that diagram of his linked in the question appears to be Kircher's own attempt to illustrate his translation off the (now) south face of the obelisk, which he translated (into Latin like you see on that diagram) as:

> 'To the triform Divinity Hemptha - first Mind, motor of all things,
> second Mind, craftsman, pantamorphic Spirit - Triune Divinity,
> eternal, having no beginning or end, Origin of the secondary Gods,
> which, diffused out of the Monad as from a certain apex into the
> breadth of the mundane pyramid, ...

It goes on in this poetic vein for quite a while, but you can see where his diagram of the pyramid with the trinity flows from this translation. The picture itself appears to be from a book he wrote about his work in 1650, [Obeliscus Pamphilius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obeliscus_Pamphilius) (Pamphilji was the pope's family name).

So when the hieroglyphs were *actually deciphered* two centuries later, thanks to the discovery of the [Rosetta Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_Stone), what did they say? "Horus, strong bull, beloved of Maat."

Oh well. Not all theories are winners, right?

Comment: I would like to see a picture if possible to verify if the circles and axis system are original as shown on the drawing. In case they are then the Rosetta Stone deciphering is very unlikly and difficult to understand.

Comment: @Jakob -  There's a nice very high-rez picture of it available off that first link I supplied. Its only one side, but its pretty clear there's no multi-word pyramid diagram on it, and no room for such a thing at the character size they used. It mostly just looks like a hieroglyphic version of a totem pole. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Obelisco_Fontana_dei_Fiumi_Piazza_Navona_Roma.jpg

Comment: Yes it is a nice hiresolution picture  and I looked at it a few times but :-( it is the wrong side. Kirchers's illustration and interpretation would make alot of sence , triform, motor of all things , origin , monad ,apex, pyramid , this is pure geometry if you know its interpretation. Since at its heart is a pyramid it seems a well founded reason for them using this very shape.

Comment: @Jakob - Its *probably* the wrong side. I'm not 100% sure, because the top hieroglyph **is** Horus. The obelisk in question does still exist though, so people are quite free to go take pictures of the other sides. Barring that, it seems reasonable to assume the other sides aren't drastically different (assuming they are different at all) from that one.